# How to Properly Set Variables (character_set_%) for Proper Cyrillic Leters Reading from MySQL in R

Tags: mysql, r, character-encoding, collation, cyrillic

I am experiencing the issue of unproper reading of cyrillic letters from MySQL table.

I use the following code:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(keyring)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), ...)
dbReadTable(mydb, 'tregions2')
```

The table is read but cyrillic letters are substituted with question marks:

```
  id     regionname  iSOID administrativeCenter
1  1 ????????? ???? RU-ALT              ???????
```

I started investigating into the issue.

The result of the query `show variables like 'character_set_%';` in MySQL Workbench for the same user logged in on the same PC returns:

```
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\
```

But result of the query returned by R is different:

```
> dbGetQuery(mydb, "show variables like 'character_set_%'")
             Variable_name                                                         Value
1     character_set_client                                                        latin1
2 character_set_connection                                                        latin1
3   character_set_database                                                          utf8
4 character_set_filesystem                                                        binary
5    character_set_results                                                        latin1
6     character_set_server                                                       utf8mb4
7     character_set_system                                                          utf8
8       character_sets_dir C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\share\\charsets\\
```

The locale variables of R are the following:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251
```

I tried to change character set and collation of the table in DB. Earlier setting cp1251 character set helped me to properly write the data into the database. But not now. I tried utf8/koi8r/cp1251 without any effect.

Attempt to execute `Sys.setlocale(,"ru_RU")` aborted with an error that it could not be executed.

I am stuck. Could anyone give me an advise what else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of investigation I finaly figured out the solution. Hope it will help someone encountering the same problem:

```
> dbExecute(mydb, "SET NAMES cp1251")
[1] 0
> dbGetQuery(mydb, "show variables like 'character_set_%'")
             Variable_name                                                         Value
1     character_set_client                                                        cp1251
2 character_set_connection                                                        cp1251
3   character_set_database                                                          utf8
4 character_set_filesystem                                                        binary
5    character_set_results                                                        cp1251
6     character_set_server                                                       utf8mb4
7     character_set_system                                                          utf8
8       character_sets_dir C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\share\\charsets\\
> 
> TrTMP <- dbReadTable(mydb, 'tregions')
> TrTMP[1,c(1,2,6,14)]
  id     regionname  iSOID administrativeCenter
1  1 Алтайский край RU-ALT              Барнаул
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tool -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

options(encoding = "UTF-8") at the top of my main script from which I call my package seems to fix the issue with having non-ascii characters in my package code.

```
read_chunk(lines = readLines("TestSpanishText.R", encoding = "UTF-8")) (also file())
```

For more flexibility, you should use utf8mb4 instead of cp1251.  If you have data coming into the client in cp1251, then you probably have to stick with that charset.